# tabPage1_Click event not triggering

Tags: c#, winforms, tabs

I am using a tab in my program to switch between two forms. I put the code required to switch between forms within the tabPage1_Click event, but it doesn't trigger when the tab is clicked.

I attached the code and properties of the tab. Please let me know if any other information is required to know the problem. Thanks.

```
private void tabPage1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Hide();
    Home form2 = new Home();
    form2.ShowDialog();
    this.Close();
}
```

[image: Properties of the tab]

[image: Updated properties]

Comment: Click on the lightning bolt in your screenshot. Take a screenshot of it. Please post it.

Comment: I uploaded it with the update

Comment: Just to be clear, Event did not trigger when "tab is selected" and not clicking inside the tabpage?

Comment: When clicking, I made another edit to make it more clear.

Comment: Thanks, john, I didn't know that events needed to be selected from the properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 things involved here. Tab control and Tab pages. Tab Control is the parent object which has multiple Tab pages in it.

You have event handler for Tab Page which is tabpage1_Click and not for Tab Control.

tabpage1_Click will be triggered when you click on tab page 1(not on the tab page header).

If you need to capture an event when you click on tab page header use Tab Control click event, something like below.

```
private void tabControl1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //Your code goes here
}
```

To access the properties of the tab page use `tabControl1.SelectedTab`